# Doctrine tries to insert a null object Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

when i submit my form, I have two values ​​to choose from:
WorkPlanningDay and workPlanningHour.

if workplanninghour is specified, we insert a row in the workplanninghour table and vice versa

When I submit a workPlanningHour, I want to prevent doctrine from inserting a workPlanningDay object with null data. I tried to use a $form->remove but without success.

here is my request datas :

```
{"statuses":[6],"work_planning":1,"work_planning_hour":{"count_jrtt":1,"end_at":"31-12","jrtt":true,"lower_hour_jrtt":35,"nbr_jrtt":24,"start_at":"01-01","upper_hour_jrtt":39},"work_planning_period":0,"working_time_aspect":{"days":["MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI"],"time":0,"weekly_hours":35}}
```

here is my form with my EventListener :

```
class WorkingTimeParametersRESTType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('work_planning', Field\ChoiceType::class, array(
                'property_path'     => 'workPlanning',
                'required'          => true,
                'choices'           => WorkingTimeParameters::getAllowedWorkPlannings(),
            ))
            ->add('work_planning_period', Field\ChoiceType::class, array(
                'property_path'     => 'workPlanningPeriod',
                'required'          => false,
                'choices'           => WorkingTimeParameters::getAllowedWorkPlanningPeriods(),
            ))
            ->add('working_time_aspect', WorkingTimeAspectType::class, array(
                'property_path' => 'workingTimeAspect',
                'required'      => true,
                'constraints'   => array(new Valid())
            ))
            ->add('work_planning_hour', WorkPlanningHourType::class, array(
                'property_path' => 'workPlanningHour',
                'required'      => true,
                'constraints'   => array(new Valid())
            ))
            ->add('work_planning_day', WorkPlanningDayType::class, array(
                'property_path' => 'workPlanningDay',
                'required'      => true,
                'constraints'   => array(new Valid())
            ))
            ->add('statuses', Field\CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'    => CategoryIntegerType::class,
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'category_type' => Category::TYPE_STATUS,
                ),
                'allow_add'         => true,
                'allow_delete'      => true,
                'required'          => true,
                'error_bubbling'    => false,
            ))
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'))
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                /** @var WorkingTimeParameters $contract */
                $parameters = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();
//                dd($form->has('work_planning_day'));
                // Remove useless work planning
                
                if ($parameters->getWorkPlanning() == Contract::WORK_PLANNING_HOUR) {
                    $parameters->setWorkPlanningDay(null);
                    $form->remove('work_planning_day');
                   
                }
                else if ($parameters->getWorkPlanning() == Contract::WORK_PLANNING_DAY) {
                    $parameters->setWorkPlanningHour(null);
                    $form->remove('work_planning_hour');
                }
                else {
                    dd('rerer');
                    $form->remove('work_planning_day');
                    $form->remove('work_planning_hour');
                    $parameters->setWorkPlanningDay(null);
                    $parameters->setWorkPlanningHour(null);
                    $parameters->setWorkPlanningPeriod(null);
                }
            })

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $rttParameters = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // The company can be set only on creation
        if (!$rttParameters || !$rttParameters->getId()) {
            $form->add('company', CompanyIntegerType::class, array(
                'required'  => true,
            ));
        }
    }
```

and here are the requests that doctrine is trying to launch :

```
INSERT INTO w2d_tm_work_planning_hour (startAt, endAt, jrtt, countJrtt, lowerHourJrtt, upperHourJrtt, nbrJrtt) VALUES ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1970-12-31 00:00:00', 1, 1, 35, 39, 24);


UPDATE w2d_tm_work_planning_day SET startAt = NULL, endAt = NULL, nbrDays = NULL, nbrJrtt = NULL WHERE id = 1;
```

how to do so that doctrine does not launch the second request with the null values ?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony form type are not made to handle different entities depending on a option you selected inside.
This not how Symfony FormType are supposed to be used. This is why the data_class attribute is made for one entity.

You best option is to create two distinct FormType and submit only the one needed depending on what the user selected on frontend. (easy with a little of javascript)
The second advantage of this is you will have much more understandable and maintable code.